# iPhone/iPad memory issue (not leak)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory, memory-leaks

The problem that I have is that the app starts to receive memory warnings after about 30-60 minutes of use.. and crash. I know, you all wants to say that I have a leaks in my app... But NO!, I don't have it, you can see it from leak analyzer screenshot. And also, I did a clean up/refactoring so many times so I'm really sure it's not a leaks.

As I understand the root of the problem - the objects released correctly, but the part of the freed memory do not goes to the app for re-use but stack somewhere... possibly I'm wrong.. Waiting for your comments

Thanks in advance

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should first try to reproduce your problem quickly, i.e. identify the operations that cause the problem, so that you can test within a minute and not within an hour. Then look at the objects that keep living and where they come from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there are leaks and then there is abandoned memory.

A leak is a situation where you have memory allocated and no longer have a reference to it, so you **can't** release it.

But it could be that you have abandoned memory which is objects you don't need anymore but to which you're still maintaining references.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, you were right. I had a TTSearchlightLabel object that had a NSTimer inside and I should call [obj stopAnimation]; in dealloc. So basically, timer retains the object and do some tasks with it with no end... uh, it was really hard one! thanks for the hint